# Is there IO functionality to store trained models in kedro?

Tags: python, kedro

In the [IO section of the kedro API docs](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.html#) I could not find functionality w.r.t. storing trained models (e.g. `.pkl`, `.joblib`, `ONNX`, `PMML`)? Have I missed something?

Comment: They should have called it artifacts instead of datasets =) It's a bit counter-intuitive that models are saved in `data` with the `datasets` plugin. And I think if it were artifacts it would have been very obvious to do classes for saving Keras / PyTorch / :hugging-face: / Tensorflow models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [`pickle`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.PickleLocalDataSet.html#kedro.io.PickleLocalDataSet) dataset in `kedro.io`, that you can use to save trained models and/or anything you want to pickle and is serialisable (models being a common object). It accepts a `backend` that defaults to `pickle` but can be set to `joblib` if you want to use `joblib` instead.

I'm just going to quickly note that Kedro is moving to [`kedro.extras.datasets`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.html) for its datasets and moving away from having non-core datasets in `kedro.io`. You might want to look at `kedro.extras.datasets` and in Kedro 0.16 onwards [`pickle.PickleDataSet`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kedro.extras.datasets.pickle.PickleDataSet.html#kedro.extras.datasets.pickle.PickleDataSet) with `joblib` support.

The Kedro [`spaceflights`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_tutorial/02_tutorial_template.html) tutorial in the documentation actually saves the trained linear regression model using the `pickle` dataset if you want to see an example of it. The relevant section is [here](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_tutorial/04_create_pipelines.html#working-with-multiple-pipelines).

Comment: Ah, totally missed `kedro.io.PickleLocalDataSet` and `kedro.io.PickleS3DataSet`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is PickleDataSet in https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kedro.extras.datasets.pickle.PickleDataSet.html and joblib support in PickleDataSet is in the next release (see https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/blob/develop/RELEASE.md)

Comment: Great to hear that `.joblib` support will be added soon! :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

This is what it currently says in my code for the node that trains the model:

```py
    path = "data/06_models/model.keras"
    model.save(path)
    # TODO make a class for the model in the catalog
    return path
```

and the catalog.yml

```yaml
model:
  type: text.TextDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/dummy_until_I_write_my_own_class_for_read_and_write_model.txt
```

then you can read the path where you saved the model and load it again.

*Okay, this is not exactly what I have - my code has more expletives*